# PHP Regex to return height and width from style

Tags: php, regex

```
echo "Style : ".$style_src."<br>";
```

returns Style: width:1000px;height:500px

I am now trying to add the echo's of both height & width

Style: width:1000px;height:500px;

Style Height: 500

Style Width: 1000

I do not know much about regex but on regexr /height[\D]+([0-9px|\%]{0,})/ highlights height:500px

What do I need to change just to return the number 500? Do I even need regex....other easier methods?

Comment: Are these HTML tags? `<img style ... >` ?

Comment: @hwnd there are actually coming from <img style="width:1000px;height:500px;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a very simple regex like

```
width:(\d+).*height:(\d+)
```

The match group 1 will contain width and group 2 will contain height

see how the regex matches at http://regex101.com/r/uT1lH4/2

Code can be

```
$re = "/width:(\\d+).*height:(\\d+)/";
$str = "Style: width:1000px;height:500px;";

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
echo "Style Height ",$matches[1],"<br>Style Width ",$matches[2];
```

will produce output

```
Style Height 1000
Style Width 500
```

If you are not sure of the order in which order the `width` and `height` may occur, then a seperate match using two different regex would do the task

```
width:(\d+) # Matches width
height:(\d+) # Matches height
```

Thanks to  Brian Stephens for the suggestion

Comment: I would also suggest matching height and width separately, so their order doesn't matter. Do a match of `/width:(\\d+)/`, then `/height:(\\d+)/`.

Comment: @BrianStephens good point !! edited the answer to include that as well. Thank you

Comment: Doesn't this match `max-width` and `min-width`?? cause that'd be actually a problem, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$re = "/width:(?<width>\\d+).*height:(?<height>\\d+)/";
$str = "Style: width:1000px;height:500px;";

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```